# Remove Image from its folder using javascript with Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, path

I am trying to delete an Image which are generated dynamically using javascript with Asp.Net and I am only able to delete it from the div container and from not is original path.

So how do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
 $('#container').append("<div class='container a'><a href='#'><img src='uploads/" + document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value + "/" + file.name + "' width='64' height='64'/><span></span></a></div>");
 $('.container a span').live('click', function (e) {
     $(this).closest('div.container').fadeOut("normal", function () {                        
         var ImagePath ="uploads/" + document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value + "/" + file.name + "";
         var sPath = Server.MapPath(ImagePath) + dataName + fileName;
         $(sPath).remove();
     });
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete an image on the server using javascript?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Does it give some error or exception? Doer your sPath variable gives a qualified and correct path? You might add try{}catch.. to see.

Comment: Yes I have done it and it's showing the path correctly and I am able to delete it from the container but not from it's folder.

Comment: If you are trying to delete the image on the server from javascript. it is simply a no-no.

Comment: @Richard -YesI am trying to delete the image on the server.

Comment: Is there any other possiblity to do so?As soon as I remove from the container it should be able to do it from the path and can I use ajax for this?If so how can I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to directly remove an image from the server using javascript alone. The only way you can achieve this is to call a server side method to do this for you.

In terms of .NET you can achieve this by writing a method on your server and exposing it as a web service. You can then call this method using jQuery's ajax functionality passing it the image name to remove. I would suggest restricting your web service to [ajax POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) requests and, as Richard pointed out in the comments, resticting what can and can't be deleted.

Comment: Thanks Andy that what I was asking Richard that can I use Ajax within this If so how can I do that?

Comment: You should be very careful to limit the files that can be deleted by this method otherwise you will have a massive security hole. Probably best for each image to have a dynamically generated ID and use that for deleting rather than the image path.

Comment: Yes richard I have already generated a seperate Id for each file and thats a good idea.And thanks for all your help.